# Off-Canvas, fixed width left column on desktop

Tags: css, canvas

I'm trying to implement an Off Canvas layout and I'm stuck (have spent half the day trying to figure this out). I basically want to use this off canvas layout from bradfrost [Right Side Off-Canvas responsive pattern](http://codepen.io/bradfrost/pen/GybaF)

What I want is:

**On mobile** the left and the right content should each be 100% width. The left content should be the one that is displayed by default and you click on a button to slide in the right content.

**On desktop** the left content should be set to 300px width and the right content should fit the rest of the width.

It seems like in the above code example, the width on desktop is set on the right content and the left content just fits the rest of the width. I basically want the opposite of that on desktop (left content fixed width, right side fits rest of width).

Another version of the code [FOUND HERE](http://codepen.io/bradfrost/pen/sjiCv) is also similar (and might be easier to edit) but the problem is that the right content is what's displayed by default on mobile view. I need the left to be displayed by default on mobile view.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you want?
[demo](http://codepen.io/hongpidai/full/IKtAb)

Animating top/left really sucks on mobile devices. You should use css transform instead.

Comment: That is basically what I want but I don't want the right content to animate off canvas on the initial page load. I just want it to display the left content by default on mobile (no initial animation) and then when you click the toggle button it'll slide in the right content. So basically no animation until you click the toggle button. Is that possible? Thanks for your help so far!!!

Comment: That initial animation is a codepen bug. It works fine on jsbin:http://jsbin.com/evinag/1

Comment: Oh ok cool! Any reason why it doesn't toggle at all in ie8? I wasn't expecting it to animate in ie8 but I thought it would show the right content when clicking on the toggle button. Thanks so much for this. Really appreciate your help

Comment: Because classList is supported on ie10+. What that toggle function does is simply adding or removing class. There are many ways to do the same thing, such as jquery. However, old browsers (e.g., opera mini, ie9-) are lack of tons of feature. It's really hard to build a RWD page that support all of them.

Comment: Oh, only ie9+ support css transform. And according to http://caniuse.com/#search=media, ie8 doesn't even support media queries.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond in order to get ie8 to support media queries so thats not a problem. I guess I'll figure out how to re-write the javascript function in order to get it to toggle the class in a way that ie8 supports.